# Reduce gap between bars in amcharts serial bar graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

Am using **[`amcharts`](https://www.amcharts.com/)** plugin to create bar graph. Is there any ways, I can reduce distance/gap between bars both `x` an `y axis` in the graph. **[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/g380La1v/1/)**

**Code**

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "theme": "light",
    "type": "serial",
    "dataProvider": [{
        "name": "John",
        "startTime": 0,
        "endTime": 11,
        "color": "#FF0F00"
    }, {
        "name": "Joe",
        "startTime": 0,
        "endTime": 13,
        "color": "#FF9E01"
    }, {
        "name": "Susan",
        "startTime": 0,
        "endTime": 18,
        "color": "#F8FF01"
    }, {
        "name": "Eaton",
        "startTime": 0,
        "endTime": 19,
        "color": "#04D215"
    }],
    "valueAxes": [{
        "axisAlpha": 0,
        "gridAlpha": 0.1
    }],
    "startDuration": 1,
    "graphs": [{
        "balloonText": "<b>[[category]]</b><br>starts at [[startTime]]<br>ends at [[endTime]]",
        "colorField": "color",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "lineAlpha": 0,
        "openField": "startTime",
        "type": "column",
        "valueField": "endTime"
    }],
    "rotate": true,
    "columnWidth": 0.2,
    "categoryField": "name",
    "categoryAxis": {
        "gridPosition": "start",
        "axisAlpha": 0,
        "gridAlpha": 0.1,
        "position": "left"
    },
    "export": {
        "enabled": true
     }
});
```

Comment: by making the graph smaller? By making the bars thicker? or by reducing the margin between them :)?

Comment: Except the 2nd option, it would be glad if you let me know other 2 options @PierreDuc :) Making graph smaller would be reducing `html` `width` and `height` of `div` if am not wrong.. How about 3rd option? :)

Comment: 3rd is done by a mix of the first and second :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the graph smaller, and reduce the margin, you have to change the `columnWidth` and the height in the css:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kcdfxrqm/1/)

By changing the height of the graph to 200px:

```
#chartdiv {
    width   : 100%;
    height  : 200px;
}
```

And setting the columnWidth to `0.8`, I think you get what you want :)

**addendum**

To remove the horizontal gray lines you can set the `gridAlpha` to 0 in the `categoryAxis`

```
"categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "position": "left"
}
```

Updated the fiddle

Comment: Awesome.. Thanks much buddy.. Accepting in few hours.. Out for lunch now.. :) Again thanks for your time.. :)

Comment: Hey buddy.. One small doubt.. Is there any way I can remove that horizontal gray lines in the chart.. I want to keep only vertical lines.. :) Let me know whenever you are free.. :)

Comment: Awesome again.. :) Thanks much.. Appreciate buddy.. :) Cannot +1 here.. So Will +1 on your any other answers... ;)

Comment: Buddy.. Mind helping on **[this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38350896/creating-serial-bar-graph-for-complex-data-amcharts)**? :)