# creating serial bar graph for complex data amcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

Below is the response I get as `json` from server:

```
[{
  "data1": {
    "name": "Test1",
    "count": 0,
    "amount": 0,
    "amtData": [
      0,0,0,0
    ],
    "cntData": [
      0,0,0,0
    ],
    "color": "#FF0F00"
  },
  "data2": {
    "name": "Test2",
    "count": 1,
    "amount": 4164,
    "amtData": [
      4164,0,0,0
    ],
    "cntData": [
      1,0,0,0
    ],
    "color": "#FF0F00"
  },
  "data3": {
    "name": "Test3",
    "count": 1,
    "amount": 2509,
    "amtData": [
      2509,0,0,0
    ],
    "cntData": [
      1,0,0,0
    ],
    "color": "#FF0F00"
  },
  "data4": {
    "name": "Test4",
    "count": 1,
    "amount": 9909,
    "amtData": [
      9909,0,0,0
    ],
    "cntData": [
      1,0,0,0        
    ],
    "color": "#FF0F00"
  },
  "data5": {
    "name": "Test5",
    "count": 0,
    "dollars": 0,
    "amount": [
      0,0,0,0
    ],
    "cntData": [
      0,0,0,0
    ],
    "color": "#FF0F00"
  }
}]
```

and here am trying to create my `chart`.

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "theme": "light",
  "type": "serial",
  "dataProvider": data, //assigning it as data
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "<b>[[category]]</b><br>starts at [[count]]<br>ends at [[amount]]",
    "colorField": "color",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "openField": "count", //base start field
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "amount" //value field
  }],
  "rotate": true,
  "columnWidth": 0.8,
  "categoryField": "name", //name field
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "position": "left"
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
});
```

How much ever I try, I am getting undefined instead of `chart`.. No `console errors` either I could make use of. How can I go restructuring this complex data and produce a graph out of it?

Here is the **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/kcdfxrqm/2/)** and this is just **[sample fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/kcdfxrqm/3/)** which I was referring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `data1` to `data5` properties from your `dataProvider`:

```
var data = [
  {
    "name": "Test1",
    "count": 0,
    "amount": 0,
    "amtData": [
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0
    ],
    "cntData": [
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0
    ],
    "color": "#FF0F00"
  },
  ...
];
```

Look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2r78xe9j/)

Comment: Wow.. Come on mahn.. I just cannot believe as so simple.. :) One more question.. Did you just expertise this plugin anytime?? ;)

Comment: Coincidentally I played with it a bit last week :) but it is a pretty good straight forward tool

Comment: Thank god.. :) I would like to know few more about this.. Would you mind helping buddy?? It will be wierd to ask separate question again.. :) Just 2 to 3 ques that's it.. :)

Comment: Sure! just ask, and ill try to answer them!

Comment: Ok.. consider I pass array of colors and want it to split to each array of amount in same `bar`.. How could I achieve it? **[Sample fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/2r78xe9j/1/)**.. I will provide you the image soon..

Comment: Just like **[image here](https://s32.postimg.org/z8kdhhx5h/testamount.png)**.. You see 4 different colors for 4 different `amount` and `count`.. Same way.. Is this achievable? That was achieved with `RGraph.js`, but now we are moving to `amcharts`.. :)

Comment: Do you want 4 bars to be merged into one? Or still 4 bars, but all bars have different colours at certain points. And how do you define at what point it should change then :)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117213/discussion-between-guruprasad-rao-and-pierreduc).

Comment: Buddy.. Am facing an issue with colors and columns.. :( Could you please assist?

Comment: I've got a meeting now, which will take a while. Try to make a question and ill see if i can find it when im done :)

Comment: Hey, its fine.. I resolved it.. :) I was supposed to pass `colorField` from `server` result, instead of assigning `color` directly in the `graph`.. Even though values are same, not sure why this behavior.. :)